# Unit testing Retrofit api call with Mockito - ArgumentCaptor

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit2

Pardon me if my question looks duplicated but I am not getting how to test retrofit API call.
**build.gradle** at application level

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.expressoVersion", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.ext.butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.ext.butterKnifeVersion"

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$rootProject.ext.hamcrestVersion"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$rootProject.ext.powerMockito"
    compile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"

    // retrofit, gson
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.ext.gsonVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retrofitVersion"
}
```

**build.gradle** at project level has this extra content

// Define versions in a single place

```
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 25
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.2'

    supportLibraryVersion = '23.4.0'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    powerMockito = '1.6.2'
    hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
    runnerVersion = '0.5'
    rulesVersion = '0.5'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    gsonVersion = '2.6.2'
    retrofitVersion = '2.0.2'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.5.1'
    expressoVersion = '2.2.2'
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {

    @BindView(R.id.textViewApiData)
    TextView mTextViewApiData;
    @BindView(R.id.progressBarLoading)
    ProgressBar mProgressBarLoading;

    private MainPresenter mMainPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        initializeComponents();
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
        mMainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this);
        mMainPresenter.presentDataFromApi();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(final String response) {
        mTextViewApiData.setText(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorReceived(final String message) {
        mTextViewApiData.setText(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgressDialog(final boolean enableProgressDialog) {
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(enableProgressDialog ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**MainView**

```
public interface MainView {

    void onResponseReceived(String response);

    void onErrorReceived(String message);

    void showProgressDialog(boolean enableProgressDialog);
}
```

**ApiClient**

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit sRetrofit;
    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (sRetrofit == null) {
            sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.Urls.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return sRetrofit;
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class MainPresenter {
    private final MainView mMainView;
    private final Call<List<UserResponse>> mCallListUserResponse;

    public MainPresenter(final MainView mainView) {
        this.mMainView = mainView;
        final ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
        mCallListUserResponse = apiInterface.getUsers();
    }

    public void presentDataFromApi() {
        mMainView.showProgressDialog(true);
        mCallListUserResponse.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final Call<List<UserResponse>> call,
                                   final Response<List<UserResponse>> response) {
                mMainView.onResponseReceived(Constants.DummyData.SUCCESS);
                mMainView.showProgressDialog(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(final Call<List<UserResponse>> call, final Throwable t) {
                mMainView.onErrorReceived(Constants.DummyData.ERROR);
                mMainView.showProgressDialog(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET(Constants.Urls.USERS)
    Call<List<UserResponse>> getUsers();
}
```

**Constants**

```
public class Constants {
    public class Urls {
        public static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
        public static final String USERS = "/users";
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do and it's not working. Test case will pass for now as i have commented 3 of the last lines. You can view the error once you un-comment those lines.
**TestCase**

```
public class MainPresenterTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainPresenter mMainPresenter;
    @Mock
    private MainView mMockMainView;
    @Mock
    private Call<List<UserResponse>> mUserResponseCall;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<List<UserResponse>>> mArgumentCaptorUserResponse;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void presentDataFromApiTest() throws Exception {
        mMainPresenter.presentDataFromApi();
        verify(mMockMainView).showProgressDialog(true);
//        verify(mUserResponseCall).enqueue(mArgumentCaptorUserResponse.capture());
//        verify(mMockMainView).onResponseReceived(Constants.DummyData.SUCCESS);
//        verify(mMockMainView).showProgressDialog(false);
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mUserResponseCall.enqueue(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.example.ranaranvijaysingh.testingdemo.presenters.MainPresenterTest.presentDataFromApiTest(MainPresenterTest.java:69)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: please add the complete test class.. how are you injecting the mocks? using the runner or via MockitoAnnotations.initMocks?

Comment: I am using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) in setUp method.

Comment: I think your problem is that you need to add @InjectMocks to mMainPresenter, and userResponseCall should be a field of your presenter, not a local variable.

Comment: I tried @InjectMocks with mMainPresenter and made the userResponseCall as field in presenter. Still getting same error.

Comment: please add the complete classes, so I can try in my machine.

Comment: This is pretty much entire code. I have cleaned the code and if you want you can clone it from https://github.com/RanaRanvijaySingh/TestingDemo.git Checkout to mockito-demo branch. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: project does not build.. if you can fix it, I'll be glad to take a look to the test

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue so have updated my question. You will find all the classes you need here itself.

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh can you share you final test case presentDataFromApiTest()  coz i dont see your using any matcher

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh ive already cloned your repo , my question is how to you validate your test case ?

Comment: My accepted answer works just fine. All you have to do is replace my "presentDataFromApiTest"  function with @Shivendra's. In my code I was missing the 2 step mentioned by Shivendra. For testing, you can now pass error response and success response and check if correct function is getting triggered or not.

Comment: Thank you @RanaRanvijaySingh , the solution is working fine with me, I have one more thing, how will you test whether `onResponse()` & `onFailure()` got called or not in the same test case?

Comment: I am not sure of it but if the param for onResponse and onFailure is same then you can try in the same case or you need to write another captor for the failure case.

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh, In your code how will you test `mMainView.onResponseReceived(Constants.DummyData.SUCCESS)` this function got called or not?

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh, my code is working fine till `enqueue` but I am not able to check whether `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` got called. If you can suggest me something that will be more helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct syntactically. However, I suspect that the @InjectMock is not able to inject the mock object to the final instance variables. It is possible that when you call mMainPresenter.presentDataFromApi(), the variable below is being used as real instance:

```
private final Call<List<UserResponse>> mCallListUserResponse;
```

You should try injecting the mock variable manually into this class and assign to mCallListUserResponse to be able to gain from mockito instantiation.

It might worth trying following steps:

1. Make the variable mCallListUserResponse in MainPresenter as non-final.
2. Add a method in class MainPresenter as below:

   void setUserResponseCall(Call> userResponse){
      mCallListUserResponse = userResponse; 
   }
3. Now in Test class do the following:

Modify your test as below

```
@Test
public void presentDataFromApiTest() throws Exception {
        //Set mock instance of the user response
        mMainPresenter.setUserResponseCall(mUserResponseCall);

        //real object call to presentDataFromApi();
        mMainPresenter.presentDataFromApi();

        verify(mMockMainView).showProgressDialog(true);    
      verify(mUserResponseCall).enqueue(mArgumentCaptorUserResponse.capture());
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Shivendra Tiwari but he hasnt tested the test case right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow some steps:

1. inject your mocks via runner or via code:

   ```
   @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
   ```

   or

   ```
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
   ```
2. annotate with `@Mock` the fields you want to mock
3. annotate with `@InjectMocks` whe field you want to test (in your case the presenter)
4. make sure the fields you want to mock are fields in the class you want to test (not local variables, like `userResponseCall` in your example), otherwise those fields will not be injected.

check this for a similar example: https://github.com/matoelorriaga/pokemon/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/melorriaga/pokemon/presenter/MainPresenterTest.java

Comment: Thanx for the reply, i tried this but still getting same error.